# Why does this C code (reading a file) crash upon exit (or file reallocation)?

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, heap-memory, variable-length-array

The following code crashes right before upon program exit. I have tested it on both MSVS 2015 and GCC. The program is just assigning a VLA on the heap (read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) if you want) and reads a file contents character by character and storing this character in the array. The program works perfectly well. It does and prints everything correctly. However upon exiting it crashes, or it ceases to respond.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define rows 8
#define columns 8

// allocate a VLA on the heap
void allocateVLArray(int x, int y, char(**ptr)[rows][columns])
{
    *ptr = malloc(sizeof(char[rows][columns]));
    assert(*ptr != NULL);
}

int main()
{
    char (*grid)[rows][columns];
    allocateVLArray(rows, columns, &grid);

    if (grid) {
        FILE *inputFile = fopen("test_fgetc.txt", "r");
        if (inputFile) {
            int x = 0, y = 0, length = 0;
            char ch;

            while((ch = (char)fgetc(inputFile)) != EOF) {
                // CR and LF characters are captured together (if necessary) and counted as one char using '\n'
                if (ch == '\n') {
                    x++; y = 0;
                }
                else {
                    *grid[x][y] = ch;
                    y++;
                }
                length++;
            }

            for (x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
                for (y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
                    printf("%c", *grid[x][y]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }

            printf("\nlength = %d\n", length);
        }
    }

    free(grid);

    return 0;
}
```

I've also noticed my constant memory usage has increased significantly, which means memory leaks. So It is probably a heap problem. Why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: None of the code inside if (grid) {} should be allocating memory, unless there's something wrong with your library's printf() implementation.

Comment: `*grid[x][y]` --> `(*grid)[x][y]`. Also `*grid` isn't VLA.

Comment: it's not crashing for me btw, but I don't have your test_fgetc.txt

Comment: your `allocateVLArray` accepts `int x, int y` and it does nothing with them.  This means that you probably do not have all warnings enabled. (`-Wall` compiler parameter.)

Comment: The virtually universal conversion is that y counts rows and x counts columns.  Please do not invent your own conventions.  Or at least if you do, then do not take that to stackoverflow.

Comment: Also `char ch;` --> `int ch;` for comparison with `EOF`.

Comment: Too complicated. Why not return the VLA?

Comment: Show `test_fgetc.txt`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `grid` is a VLA allocated on the heap. Its a new thing (read that link i posted if you want). The mistake was the one you mentioned. I did `*grid[x][y]` and not `(*grid)[x][y]`. `[]` have higher precedence than `*`. I should have known. Everything else said here was wrong. `-Wall` was enabled, but `Wextra` was not. You can make it into an answer, so i can accept it.

Comment: this line: `*ptr = malloc(sizeof(char[rows][columns]));` should be: `*ptr = malloc( rows*columns );   Note: it is not a VLA array if placed on the heap

Comment: the posted code fails to handle the case where the call to `fopen()` fails

Comment: this line: `while((ch = (char)fgetc(inputFile)) != EOF) {` will fail to catch `EOF if `char` is defined as `unsigned`.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Comment: what if the row in the file contains more than 8 characters?  What if the file contains more than 8 rows?  what if a row contains less than 8 characters?  what if the file contains less than 8 rows?

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings then fix those warnings.  For instance, the function: `allocateVLArray()` has two unused parameters: `x` and `y`.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra `*grid` isn't VLA. Because `char (*grid)[rows][columns];` : `rows` and `columns` are defined by macro as constant `8`, not variable. So `char (*grid)[rows][columns];` is fix array that same as  `char (*grid)[8][8];` (Also I think that MSVC2015 does not support VLA yet.)

Comment: So `malloc(sizeof(char[rows][columns]))` is fix array allocated on heap, not _VLA allocated on the heap_.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Post an answer, so i can accept it.

Comment: You can post your answers yourself. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that your `"test_fgetc.txt"` contains more than 64 characters, or more than 8 rows of characters.  That would exhibit precisely the behavior that you are experiencing: it would appear to work, and it would crash on `free()`.